# Java, How to add values to Array List used as value in HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

What I have is a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` called `examList`. What I want to use it for is to save grades of each course a person is attending. So key for this `HashMap` is `couresID`, and value is a `ArrayList` of all grades (exam attempts) this person has made.

The problem is I know how to work with array lists and hashmaps normally, but I'm not sure how to even begin with this example. So how would I, or example, add something to `ArrayList` inside `HashMap`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could either use the Google Guava library, which has implementations for Multi-Value-Maps (Apache Commons Collections has also implementations, but without generics).

However, if you don't want to use an external lib, then you would do something like this:

```
if (map.get(id) == null) { //gets the value for an id)
    map.put(id, new ArrayList<String>()); //no ArrayList assigned, create new ArrayList

map.get(id).add(value); //adds value to list.
```

Comment: There's also Spring MultiValueMap and LinkedMultiValueMap

Comment: Nice example, exactly what a Java n00b like me required.

Answer (score 8):

```
String courseID = "Comp-101";
List<String> scores = new ArrayList<String> ();
scores.add("100");
scores.add("90");
scores.add("80");
scores.add("97");

Map<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
myMap.put(courseID, scores);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and how can i get the keys,values?

Comment: @David Use the HashMap's keySet() method. It will return all keys which in the above example would be Strings. Then for each key, you can get the corresponding ArrayList<String> by using the HashMap's get(key) method, where 'key' is the keys you retrieved earlier. Hope this helps!

Comment: @greenhorn No problem!

Answer (score 4):

- First create HashMap.

  HashMap> mapList = new HashMap>();
- Get value from HashMap against your input key.

  ArrayList arrayList = mapList.get(key);
- Add value to arraylist.

  arrayList.add(addvalue);
- Then again put arraylist against that key value.
  mapList.put(key,arrayList);

It will work.....

Comment: Is it necessary to put the arraylist back into the hashmap? or is an item added by reference?

Comment: No, you don't have to put the list back in mapList, you can skip the final step listed here.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8+ has **[Map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)** for such cases:

```java
examList.compute(courseId, (id, grades) ->
        grades != null ? grades : new ArrayList<>())
    .add(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

First you retreieve the value (given a key) and then you add a new element to it

```
    ArrayList<String> grades = examList.get(courseId);
    grades.add(aGrade);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to lookup the correct `ArrayList` in the `HashMap`:

```
ArrayList<String> myAList = theHashMap.get(courseID)
```

Then, add the new grade to the `ArrayList`:

```
myAList.add(newGrade)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also do this in Kotlin without using any external libraries.

```
var hashMap : HashMap<String, MutableList<String>> = HashMap()

if(hashMap.get(id) == null){
        hashMap.put(id, mutableListOf<String>("yourString"))
} else{
        hashMap.get(id)?.add("yourString")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<ObjectX>> objList = new HashMap<>();

if(objList.containsKey(key))
   objList.get(key).add(Object1);
else
   objList.put(key, new ArrayList<ObjectX>(Arrays.asList(Object1)));
```